Using a single .drl file in multiple ruleunit classes
I am trying to migrate to drools ruleunits from traditional drools (v7->v9). I have some .drl files that belong to multiple ksessions. The ruleunit documentation specifies that you can declare only one unit per .drl file. Is there a way to include a .drl file in multiple ruleunits ?
Use the following as an example:
src/main/resources/basePackage/rulesA.drl
     package basePackage;
     //multiple rules

src/main/resources/basePackage/rulesB.drl
     package basePackage;
     //multiple rules

src/main/java/basePackage.RulesA
     public class RuleUnitA implements RuleUnitData {
       //corresponding dataStores and global variables for rulesA.drl 
       //only uses rulesA.drl
} 

src/main/java/basePackage.RulesAB
     public class RuleUnitAB implements RuleUnitData {
       //corresponding dataStores and global variables for rulesA.drl and rulesB.drl
       //uses rulesA.drl both rulesB.drl
} 

The workaround for the above example would be to create separate packages and duplicate rulesA.drl.
Something like:
src/main/resources/basePackage/rulesA/rulesA.drl
     package basePackage.rulesA;
     unit RuleUnitA;
     //multiple rules

src/main/resources/basePackage/rulesAB/rulesA.drl
     package basePackage.rulesAB;
     unit RuleUnitAB;
     //multiple rules
     //same file as the one above

src/main/resources/basePackage/rulesAB/rulesB.drl
     package basePackage.rulesAB;
     unit RuleUnitAB;
     //multiple rules

src/main/java/basePackage.rulesA.RulesA

     public class RuleUnitA implements RuleUnitData {
       //corresponding dataStores and global variables for rulesA.drl 
       //only uses rulesA.drl
} 

src/main/java/basePackage.rulesAB.RulesAB
     public class RuleUnitAB implements RuleUnitData {
       //corresponding dataStores and global variables for rulesA.drl and rulesB.drl
       //uses rulesA.drl both rulesB.drl
    } 

